# Angular material sidenav and expansion insert padding to the left, why?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I try to make the simplest of foldable left side nav bars,
but it does not stick to the left and instead gets padded
so it ends up in the middle of the page.

There is no CSS.
The amount of padding is depending on the length of the word "Overview".

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-expansion-panel>

        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            Overview
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>

    </mat-sidenav-content>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a `<mat-sidenav-content>` to many, namely the first one.

The correct code should be:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <mat-expansion-panel>

      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Overview
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    </mat-expansion-panel>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```